# Add multiple values to arraylist from user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add to my array list, then print out the list off all the programmers. Instead it just prints out the single programmer I just entered the details for. My question is. How do you correctly put the information entered into my Array list Programmer? Adding one array to another.

```
public Programmer(int id, String name, double pay, String time, int managerId) {
    this.mId = id;
    this.mName = name;
    this.mPay = pay;``
    this.mTime = time;
    this.mManagerId = managerId;
    this.mManager = null;
```

---

```
case 4:

    String nameadd, time , manager;
    double pay;
    int manageradd;

    System.out.println("Enter new car data:");

    nameadd = in.getString("Name: ");
    pay = in.getDouble("Wage: ");
    time = in.getString("Part or Full Time: ");
    manageradd = in.getInt("Manager ID: ");

    p = ui.insert(nameadd, time, pay, manageradd );
    System.out.println(p.getName() + ": WAGE: €" + p.getPay()+ " STATUS:" + p.getTime() + " MANAGER: " + p.getManager());

    }

    break;
```

---

And heres my View

```
public Programmer insert(String nameadd, String time, double pay, int manageradd) {

    Programmer p;

    p = new Programmer(0, nameadd, pay, time, manageradd);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: where are you adding anything to a list or array?

Comment: So essentially, you are just trying to create an ArrayList of Programmers?

Comment: you must put an arraylist

         nameadd = in.getString("Name: ");
         pay = in.getDouble("Wage: ");
         time = in.getString("Part or Full Time: ");
         manageradd = in.getInt("Manager ID: ");
         List<Programmer> lstProgrammer = new ArrayList<Programmer>();
         p1 = ui.insert(nameadd, time, pay, manageradd );
         lstProgrammer.add(p);
         
         for (Programmer p: lstProgrammer) {
System.out.println(p.getName() + ": WAGE: €" + p.getPay()+ "      STATUS:" + p.getTime() + " MANAGER: " + p.getManager());
         }

Comment: Oh, Ah I see now that I wasn't adding to anything.. just printing what I had entered. thanks.

Comment: I didnt make it clear that I already have values stored in the array. I want to add to this list. 
mProgrammers.add(new Programmer(1, "Charlie Chaplin", 30000, "Full Time", 1));
        mProgrammers.add(new Programmer(2, "James Pilkington", 31000, "Full Time", 1));
        mProgrammers.add(new Programmer(3, "Shane Peterson", 30000, "Full Time", 1));
        mProgrammers.add(new Programmer(4, "Jamie Farely", 30000, "Full Time", 1));
        mProgrammers.add(new Programmer(5, "Philip Roberts", 33000, "Full Time", 1));

Comment: Arrays.asList()?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of your method or inside your class initialize the list.

```
List<Programmer> listOfProgrammers = new ArrayList<Programmer>();
```

Then you can add your programmers when they are created.

```
listOfProgrammers.add(p);
```